# PHP: Active record table joins

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an app that uses the codeigniter CXTags tagging library.

The database structure is as follows:

**posts**

id

**tags_ref**

row_id

table

tag_id

**tags**

id

safe_tag

tag

My query basically goes if $safe_tag is not null then join tags_ref on post.id = tags_ref.row_id, join tags on tags_ref.tag_id = tags.id, where tags_ref.table = 'posts' and tags.safe_tag = 'food'

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
JOIN tags_ref ON posts.id = tags_ref.row_id
JOIN tags ON tags_ref.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.safe_tag = $safe_id
```

Unfortunately the query I've written in active record is not functioning properly. The query works perfectly when £safe_tag is null but when it's not I get wrong results.

```
function get_posts($id = NULL, $safe_tag = NULL) {

    if($safe_tag != NULL){
        echo $safe_tag;//debugging
        $table = 'posts';
        $this->db->join('tags_ref', 'posts.id = tags_ref.row_id');
        $this->db->join('tags', 'tags_ref.tag_id = tags.id');
        $this->db->where('tags_ref.table', $table);
        $this->db->where('tags.safe_tag',$safe_tag);
    }

    //if an id was supplied
    if ( $id != NULL ) {
        $this->db->where('posts.city_id',$id);
    }

    // execute query
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
    ...
```

Here is the query with profiling on:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`posts`)
INNER JOIN `tags_ref` ON `posts`.`id` = `tags_ref`.`row_id`
INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags_ref`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id`
WHERE `tags_ref`.`table` = 'posts'
AND `tags`.`safe_tag` = 'food'
AND `posts`.`city_id` = '2'
```

Can someone have a look? I think I need a fresh set of eyes on it.

Comment: «Unfortunately the query I've written in active record is not fuctioning properly» — any errors or unexpected dataset returned? Can you see (debug) SQL-query as a string with your $this->db before execution?

Comment: I find the CI Active Record class to be very restrictive and only use it for updates and inserts. Beyond that just use $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?",array($id)). You wouldn't have to compromise like you seem to be doing for the additional join clause in your code and you wouldn't cause extra load on the server for parsing your active record query. Sorry I know this doesn't really answer your question, just wanted to share my thoughts.

Comment: By the way, you can see the executed queries by turning profiling on (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html).

Comment: What are the results when you run your SQL query on the database directly, and how do they differ from the results that come back when running it through Active Record?

Comment: The active record query is not the equivalent of the standard sql query you posted above - it has an additional where clause for 'tags_ref.table'?

Comment: I've updated my question with the query printed with profiling on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot to actually run the query inside your first `if{}`

```
if($safe_tag != NULL){
        echo $safe_tag;//debugging
        $table = 'posts';
        $this->db->join('tags_ref', 'posts.id = tags_ref.row_id');
        $this->db->join('tags', 'tags_ref.tag_id = tags.id');
        $this->db->where('tags_ref.table', $table);
        $this->db->where('tags.safe_tag',$safe_tag);
        $this->db->get(); // here 
    }
```