# More Waiting time in getting data from database table with large data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like 'employee' and 'employeeleaves'. Just i want to calculate how many days the employee have taken the leave for the year. 'employeeleaves' table have the leave details for last three years.
Im using adodb.inc.php lib files for database connectivity.
I have 50 employees records and 1000 records of leave taken. My application takes approximately 1 minute to get the data and displaying. When i see this in google chrome->developer tools->NEtwork, For waiting(TTFB) - 38.46s.

I want to reduce this time.Because once the 'employeeleaves' table get more data,then this waiting time will increase.
Below i paste my data fetching coding, first i take employee list and for each employee im calculating the leaves for the particular year.

```
$employee = new Employee();
        $employees = $employee->Find("1=1");        
        foreach($employees as $employee){

$employeeLeave = new EmployeeLeave();
        $employeeLeaves = $employeeLeave->Find("employee = ? and leave_period = ? and leave_type = ? and status = ?",
        array($employeeId,'2016','SickLeave','approved'));
        if(!$employeeLeaves){
            error_log($employeeLeave->ErrorMsg(),true);
        }       
        return $employeeLeaves;
}
```

Above code is for taking 'sickleave', i will use the same for ' casual leave' also.

Just i want to know, whether i can make this query to scan only the rows that contain the leave period as '2016'.

employeeleaves Table- field names

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id, employee, leave_type, leave_period, date_start, date_end, details, status, attachment |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I´m quite not sure that it´s your applications fault to run the query as slow. have you activated slowlog in your mysql? on which machinne is it running?

Comment: moreover can you perform the query manually direct on the database to see if it´s the query itself which is as slow?

Comment: Can you show us the EmployeeLeave class, specifically the Find method

Comment: In MySQL workbench, when i execute the same ,it shows result in 0 seconds when i give exact year and leave type. But in this coding, i have to loop for all employees.For each employee,im reading the same table.

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

You have 2 tables, why do you don't create a query to join into MYSQL?

It would be much better!

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
INNER JOIN employeeLeave el
ON(el.employee = e.id)
```

Comment: im using adodb active record method. i dont know how to use join in that.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695372/php-active-record-table-joins